# bootstrapValidator in XPages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, bootstrapvalidator

I have below code in my XPage, However it does not work for the given field ipAddress even it is blank, it does not prompt any validation, I also tried with #{id:ipAddress} as well, it does not work. I am using Notes 9 and Designer 9. Could anybody please help me with other way of doing field validation in XPages using bootstrapValidator functionality.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" id="testid">
            <xp:this.resources>
                <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrap.css"></xp:styleSheet>
                <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrapValidator.min.css"></xp:styleSheet>
                <xp:script src="/jquery-1.11.1.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
                <xp:script src="/bootstrap.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
                <xp:script src="/bootstrapValidator.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
                <xp:script src="/jquery.mask.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
            </xp:this.resources>
            <xp:form id="maskForm">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
      <xp:inputText id="ipAddress" title="ipAddress">
        </xp:inputText>
        </div>
            </xp:form>
            <xp:scriptBlock>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA 

var test ="view:_id1";
        var fieldvalue="#view:_id1:_id4:_id142:_id143:callback1:idLocation";
      XSP.addOnLoad( function() {
        $("#"+test).bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
           fieldvalue: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            } } }) });

            ]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:scriptBlock>
            </xp:view>

    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Attaching picture here, output after your suggestion
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuSBL.png)

[imager of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d30Jt.png)[erro 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9C23.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you check your HTML source, you will find that the `id` attributes have been altered. The HTML specs requires IDs to be unique, so JSF amends the names.

In your script block you need to store them in variables instead of using them literally.

You already did that for the form. Do that for the fields too.

**Update**

Your code probably needs to look like this (inside the CDATA):

```
      XSP.addOnLoad( function() {
     // You might need one more #
        $('#{id:maskForm}').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
           '#{id:ipAddress}': {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            } } }) });

        ]]&gt;
```

The only field in your Snippet is `ipAddress` - that's what my examples uses.
The trick here: replace static IDs with the XPages expression language that gives the actual id. Your script block processes the expressions before sending data to the browser. The browser gets data without knowing it was preprocessed.

So if you have `<input id="Color" />` you use `#{id:Color}` to get the actual id.

However you might reconsider your approach. XPages has great validators that are stored with a field and offer most of what you are looking for. Externalise the validation and you constantly need to change code when your fields change. Keep fields and validations together!

Comment: I have added below code as well but it does not work, please see above modified code in main post and I tried having these two variable as well but it does not work. var test ="view:_id1";
        var fieldvalue="#"+'#{javascript:getClientId("idLocation")}';

Comment: That code doesn’t do anything. You still have a static text fieldvalue: in your fields Json object. You need to compute that Id there.

Comment: Thanks @stwissel, please see error which I got after I got to implement your solution.

Comment: here is the error message in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuSBL.png

Comment: also I dont want to specifiy specific xp:form tag on xpage. How do I reference to default form of the xpage ? $("'view:_id1'").bootstrapValidator({ will do stuff ?

Comment: Json: if your label contains other stuff than numbers and letters you need to quote it. If you are sure that you will have only one form on the page (I wouldn’t do that) use getElementsByTagName(“form”)[0]. There is no static way to predict ids

Comment: Thanks @stwissel, but still I persist same error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d30Jt.png

Comment: Use the x$ code snippet to work with the XPages ids with colons: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages

Comment: Hi I tried with your code : as below and found error as attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9C23.png, here is original code :       x$(“#{id:idLocation}”): {

Comment: Hello Per Henrik Lausten, Can you please help me ehre